# Download Youtube playlist as mp3 in Python

Tags: python, youtube, python-re, moviepy, pytube

I'm trying to download my video playlist and convert it to mp3 extension using pytube,moviepy,re. Everything works but when it hits a number it stops working.

How can I fix this?

```py
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp #to convert the mp4 to wav then mp3
import re

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb2p41g_hNVOeBy3OjGTdXKgscedya9f_")

for url in playlist:
    print(url)
for vid in playlist.videos:
    print(vid)
for url in playlist:
    YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download("./Downloads/Music_2")
folder = "./Downloads/Music_2"
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if re.search('mp4', file):
        print("Converting: " + file)
        mp4_path = os.path.join(folder,file)
        mp3_path = os.path.join(folder,os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.mp3')
        new_file = mp.AudioFileClip(mp4_path)
        new_file.write_audiofile(mp3_path)
        os.removed(mp4_path)
```

Error Code;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projects\Python\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download("./Downloads/Music_3")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projects\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projects\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Projects\Python\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 161, in streaming_data
    return self.vid_info['streamingData']
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'streamingData'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: [I wasn't able to copy correctly the playlist id](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb2p41g_hNV0eBy30jGTdXKgscedya9f_) `PL...` from [your original code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G8w9.png), could you edit your question with the correct one please?

Comment: Could you provide the output logs please? Or just the error.

Comment: I would also recommend checking out [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#embedding-yt-dlp) instead of Pytube, as it has many more features, such as downloading an mp so you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: @Cheesebellies I shared the error message

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Sorry for posting the error message as a photo.

Comment: Maybe try checking if Pytube is updated?

Comment: [@MertK.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16227434/mert-k) Note that you haven't answered my original question (which is the first comment).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I changed the url, can you check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this one - This will download the entire playlist as webm which basically can be played as mp3, therefor I'm setting the **outtmpl** as TITLE.mp3 (to the current folder)

enjoy :)

```
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_url = input("Please insert the URL: ")
    video_info = YoutubeDL().extract_info(url=video_url, download=False)
    options = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'keepvideo': False,
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.mp3',
        # 'playlist_items': '2'
    }
    with YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
        out = ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue with the latest pytube version.

More precisely [these video ids](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2470326) failed to be downloaded on first trial. However after another trial only the following video ids are still not available for download: [`bFfSn7RKgwE`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFfSn7RKgwE), [`pYEwoUgKhV8`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYEwoUgKhV8) and [`UtF6Jej8yb4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtF6Jej8yb4). [`pYEwoUgKhV8`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYEwoUgKhV8) is a members-only video so you are obliged to pay to access it and [`bFfSn7RKgwE`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFfSn7RKgwE) and [`UtF6Jej8yb4`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtF6Jej8yb4) are just age-restricted, you can access these videos with [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) for instance.

So there is no pytube issue here.

Answer (score -1):

I tried. The script was fine, until the last line:

```
 os.removed(mp4_path)
```

It should be  `os.remove(mp4_path)`

*Without the 'd'

Comment: In original code execute fix `YouTube(url).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(output_path="./Downloads/Music_2")`

And line `os.remove(mp4_path)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).